# ng-repeat selected row css when using three different accordions

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, json, object

I have three java-script objects that populate 3 different accordions. 
var a[](Populates accordion a); var b[](Populates accordion b); var c[](Populates accordion c);
I would want to change the CSS of the selected row when any one row is selected in any accordion. How do I toggle (remove background color and add background color) when I have data from three different objects?

Any pointers on how to solve this in angularjs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll have to reset the other 2 accordions by code when one is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Since no html was provided here's a very simple example of using `ng-click` for selecting an item and `ng-class` dependent on selected item

Controller

```
$scope.items=[/* data objects */];
$scope.selected = null;
$scope.selectItem = function(item){
  $scope.selected = item;
}
```

View

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" 
     ng-click="selectitem(item}" 
     ng-class="{selected: selectedItem == item}">
      {{item.someprop}}
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.selected { background:yellow}
```

Comment: Would this work when I have three different divs having ng-repeat?. In my usecase, I have three different ng-repeats getting data from their own specific javascript objects. But the catch is when one row in div1 is selected all others div rows should be deselected and likewise.

Comment: Need to show your template structure in question and not just talk about what you have